# Difficulty sending JSON to Web API 2

Tags: json, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am having a hard time pleasing Web API 2 and trying to get it to process my JSON in an HTTP POST correctly. I am expecting the value of `UploadRequest.RequestItems[0].ItemTypeId` to be 1.

My JSON looks like this:

```
claim = {
    "UploadRequests": [
        {
            "RequestItems": [
                { itemTypes: [1] }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ClaimRef": "C/123",
    "PerilId": 1,
    "Title": 0,
    "CustomerName": "Jones",
    "Mobile": "07123123123",
    "Email": "my.email@gmail.com"
};
```

It is the `RequestItems` it is falling over on. It passes the `ModelState.IsValid`, but the `RequestItems` is not being populated as expected. A watch of the claim on the Web API endpoint looks like this:

[image]

I am expecting the `ItemTypeId` to correspond to the JSON.

My `UploadRequest` model looks like this:

```
namespace DocumentPortalShared.Models
{
    public class UploadRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClaimId { get; set; }
        public string UrlId { get; set; }
        public string RequestText { get; set; }
        public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime? ResponseDate { get; set; }

        public Claim Claim { get; set; }

        public List<RequestItem> RequestItems { get; set; }
        public List<ResponseItem> ResponseItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the `BaseItem`, from which `RequestItem` is derived, looks like this:

```
namespace DocumentPortalShared.Models
{
    public abstract class BaseItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UploadRequestId { get; set; }
        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }

        public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How should I be formatting the JSON?

Comment: You dont have `itemTypes` array inside `RequestItem` object. Try `"RequestItems": [
                { ItemTypeId: 1}
            ]`

Comment: Yes, that's great, thanks. Works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see you sepcify ItemTypeID in the JSON.
Maybe this......

```
claim = {
    "UploadRequests": [
        {
            "RequestItems": [
                { "itemTypeId":1 }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ClaimRef": "C/123",
    "PerilId": 1,
    "Title": 0,
    "CustomerName": "Jones",
    "Mobile": "07123123123",
    "Email": "my.email@gmail.com"
};
```

and if there were more than one...

```
    "RequestItems": [
        { "itemTypeId":1 },{ "itemTypeId":2 },{ "itemTypeId":3 }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you - I broke my JSON help someone cherry ;)

Comment: Hehehe. Is a beggar an obstacle to generosity?